# Should we merge [surveys] & [questionnaire]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have the following tags:

- [surveys](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveys):  14 questions
- [questionnaire](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questionnaire): 5 questions

The first, doesn't have a tag wiki tag yet, but the second has the following.

> A questionnaire is a method of research consisting of a series of
>   questions in order to gather data from participants. Use this tag when
>   seeking recommendations for software that allows the building of
>   questionnaires and the subsequent collection of data.
>
> Remember to specify required functionality, for example variety of
>   question types (multiple choice [dichotomous, *-polytomous],
>   continuous scales, etc).

IMO the same apply to both sets of questions. Could these tags be merged?

Answer (score 5):

Browsing through the questions of the former, I agree they match the tag-wiki description of the latter – so I'd say they should be merged. To avoid the "left-over" to be re-created, it should be made a synonym.

Though the second one has a tag wiki and the other one doesn't, I feel `surveys` should be the master (maybe the tag-wiki could be copied over?).

Answer (score 2):

Merged & synonymized [questionnaire](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questionnaire) -> [surveys](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveys). I forgot to copy across the tag wiki before doing so, but it'll show up in the orphan wiki list shortly. I'll watch for it and copy it across when it does.