# Should we merge [surveys] & [forms]

Tags: discussion, tags

This is related to [Should we merge [surveys] & [questionnaire]?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/should-we-merge-surveys-questionnaire)

We have the following tags:

- [surveys](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveys):  <s>20 questions</s> 23 questions
- [forms](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms): <s>22 questions</s> 19 questions

AFAIK the first, has a wiki tag that has been <s>proposed</s> recently approved.  The second doesn't has a wiki tag yet.

<s>I think that the proposed</s>The recently approved wiki tag for [surveys](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveys)  is:

> A survey is a method of research consisting of a series of questions
>   in order to gather data from participants. Use this tag when seeking
>   recommendations for software that allows the building of
>   questionnaires and the subsequent collection of data.
>
> Remember to specify required functionality, for example variety of
>   question types (multiple choice [dichotomous, *-polytomous],
>   continuous scales, etc).

IMO the same apply to both sets of questions. Could these tags be merged?

Comment: Not sure about this, some of the [forms] questions are about HTML forms and the like.

Comment: @Undo: Is [tag:forms] a meta-tag?

Comment: @Rubén I don't see what would make it a meta tag, but it may be an ambiguous tag. It is certainly not a synonym of [tag:surveys].

Answer (score 1):

Instead of merge both tags do some tag clean up (already changed the tag for four questions) and propose a wiki tag for [forms](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) to try to help solving its ambiguity.